# Display data of fields on selecting other fields

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement where I have to display Account's 2 fields (Text type) FieldA__c and FieldB__c as dropdown fields. and once selecting the values of these two fields, values of other Account's filelds (FieldC_c, FieldD_c andFieldE_c) should display. I am able to get the drop down list of FieldA_c and FieldB_c, however Im not able to get the values of FieldC_c, FieldD_c andFieldE_c. Kindly help. Below is the code:

Updated code:

Controller

```
public class AccountController{
Public String selectedName {get;set;} 
Public String selectedCategory {get;set;}   
Public List<Account> accList1{get;set;}
Public List<Account> actList1{get;set;}       


   Public List<SelectOption> getAccountList(){
   List<SelectOption>AccountList = new List<SelectOption>();
    AccountList.add(new SelectOption('','------------All-----------'));
    List<Account>actList = [Select id, name, FieldA__c , FieldB__c from Account];
    for(Account acc:actList){
        AccountList.add(new SelectOption(acc.id, pd.FieldA__c));            
    }
    return AccountList;
}

Public List<SelectOption> getAccountBList(){
   List<SelectOption>AccountBList = new List<SelectOption>();
    AccountBList.add(new SelectOption('','------------All-----------'));
    List<Account>actList = [Select id, name, FieldA__c , FieldB__c from Account];
    for(Account act:actList){
        AccountBList.add(new SelectOption(act.id, act.FieldB__c));            
    }
    return AccountBList;
}

Public PageReference ShowProduct() {
    accList = [select id, Name, FieldA__c , FieldB__c,FieldC_c, FieldD_c, FieldE_c  from Account where id =:selectedName];
    actList1 = [select id, Name, FieldA__c , FieldB__c,FieldC_c, FieldD_c, FieldE_c  from Account where id =:selectedCategory];        

    List<Account> MasterAccount = new List<Account>();
    MasterAccount.addall(accList);
    MasterAccount.addall(actList1);        

    return null;
}
```

}

Page-

```
<apex:page controller="AccountController">
```

```
        <apex:outputLabel value="Account"/>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedName}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountList }"/>
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ShowAccount}" rerender="acc"/> 
      </apex:selectList>
      </td>
      <td>
      <apex:selectList value="{!selectedCategory}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountBList }"/>
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ShowProduct}" rerender="acc"/> 
      </apex:selectList>
      </td>
      </tr>

    </apex:pageblockSection>        
<apex:pageblockSection >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="a" id="acc">
    <apex:column >                
            <apex:outputText value="{!a.FieldC_c}"  />
            <apex:outputText value="{!a.FieldD_c}"  />
            <apex:outputText value="{!a.FieldE_c}"  />
   </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>     
         </apex:pageblockSection>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to add a rerender to your actionsupports, so that the updated data is actually shown on the screen.

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ShowAccount}" rerender="acc" />
```

Also having 2 selectLists with the same binding (value) will likely cause trouble. What's the intention of that? You might want to introduce a selectedCategory2 and update the query in ShowAccount() accordingly

And lastly, you are not using your getAccountList() function, only the getAccountBList(). Both picklists are being filled from the same list.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but now its giving an error on page. Error: System.NullPointerException: Argument 2 cannot be null 
Class.AccountController.getAccountBList: line 22, column 1.                         These 2 select lists needs to act like dependent picklists on page. These 2 fields FieldA__c and FieldB__c are text type and so I cannot change them to dependent picklists at object level. I'm updaing the question with the updated code. Please help.

Comment: That error indicates that argument 2 on line 22 is empty. Looks like you have an Account with an empty FieldB__c. You need to update your code to skip those fields as you can't add null values to a selectlist.